# How to replace multiple points in qml line series using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am replacing around 1000 points every second to the Line Series in qml using replace() but it takes more cpu since i am replacing one point at a time so is there any better way to replace multiple points to the line series in qml?

```
python3:
    graph2.setProperty('oldx',xlist[i])
    graph2.setProperty('oldy',ylist[i])
    graph2.setProperty(xcord,row[0])
    graph2.setProperty(ycord,row[1])
```

```
qml:
    onYcordChanged: {
     idLineSeries.replace(oldx,oldy,xcord,ycord);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`LineSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html) has the ancestor of [`QXYSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html) so you could access the overloaded [`replace()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#replace-5) method that supports the replacement of all points at the same time but it is not exposed in QML so you will have to access from python

```py
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml, QtChart


class DataModel(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtChart.QXYSeries)
    def update_serie(self, serie):
        # generate points
        points = []
        x = 0
        while x < 10:
            x += 0.1
            y = random.uniform(-100, 100)
            point = QtCore.QPointF(x, y)
            points.append(point)
        # replace points
        serie.replace(points)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()

    dataModel = DataModel()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("dataModel", dataModel)
    file = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Timer {
        interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: dataModel.update_serie(serie)
    }
    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: bscan0
        ValueAxis {
            id: axisx
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }
        ValueAxis {
            id: axisy
            min: -100
            max: 100
        }
        LineSeries{
            id: serie
            name: "Test"
            axisX: axisx
            axisY: axisy
        }
    }
}
```